# Store free text as variable in IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: variables, bots, watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

i want to know if theres a way for IBM Watson assistant to store free text or direct input from the user as a variable. I know you can do it with number with the code below here:

```
"context" : {
    "number_extract" : "<? input.text.extract('[\\d]+',0) ?>"
}
```

But this only works with numbers. what do you do when you want to store a free text for e.g. a name as a variable?The same code doesn't work for any other text but number so i assume there must be a code which works for text or free text. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input can be simply accessed using `input.text`. [See this part of the documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#access-input).

In your sample, an additional `extract` function is applied to the input string. The parameter to the [extract function](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#strings) is a regex string (regular expression search string). In your sample, it searches for the first number. You can also search for other components, our transform the string. [See the docs for other functions you can apply](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#strings).

I have also collected [samples for working with context variables in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could i ask you one more question? Is there a way to extract these store context variables into a separate text file?

Comment: Mark this question as answered (if it answers your first question), open a new question. The idea is that each question & answer can be easily found.